# Need help to figure out a regex to modify some files

Tags: sed, regex

I have some files that  I need to clean up some names.

for example:

```
GCA_940670685.1_Clostridium_sp_chr  3757330
GCA_940677205.1_Clostridium_colinum_chr 2035557
GCA_942548115.1_Aeromicrobium_sp_chr    3463989
GCA_943169635.1_Fenollaria_sp_chr   3260126
GCA_943169825.1_Varibaculum_sp_chr  4423380
GCA_943736995.1_Sporosarcina_sp_chr 3771420
```

And I need some like this:

```
GCA_940670685.1 3757330
GCA_940677205.1 2035557
GCA_942548115.1 3463989
GCA_943169635.1 3260126
GCA_943169825.1 4423380
GCA_943736995.1 3771420
```

I tried to use:

```
sed 's/_[A-Za-z]+_//gI' Terrabacteria_chr_lengths.tsv

sed 's/\w+_\w+_chr//gI' Terrabacteria_chr_lengths.tsv

find Results/Lengths/Bacteria -type f -exec sed -i 's/_\w+_\w+_chr//g' {} \;
```

But seems nothing is working, I think due my poor skills in the regex, ex. *\w+*\w+_chr.

Any suggestion would be appreciate.
Thank you.

Paulo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that `+` does not act as a quantifier in a sed basic regular expression (BRE) - you need to switch to extended regular expression (ERE) mode using `-E` or `-r` to use that (or change `+` to `\{1,\}` for a POSIX BRE version<sup>1</sup>).

Beyond that, you seem to want to match a sequence of alphabetic characters *and underscores* after the initial underscore (but **not** ending with an underscore). So either:

```
sed -E 's/_[A-Za-z_]+//'
```

or

```
sed 's/_[A-Za-z_]\{1,\}//'
```

You **don't** need the `g` modifier, since you're making a single substitution per line.

---

<sup>1</sup> GNU sed actually supports `\+` as a quantifier in BRE, but IMHO that just adds to the confusion.

Comment: Thank you very much.